# How to embed a game built in VB on a webpage

Tags: html, vb.net, embed

I have a built a hangman game in Visual Basic. How can i embed this in a html page so that people visiting my website can play the game.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can port your game to Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

With great difficulty: you would have to make the VB game into an ActiveX control and embed that ActiveX control into the page. Take a look at [this](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson13/) for an old guide: note that it would only work in IE.

Comment: And then you can be cursed for writing an IE-only webpage.

Comment: Hahahaha. Cursed doesn't entirely capture the level of contempt that one should expect for building IE-only pages.